# WaitForSingleObject signalled immediately

Tags: c#, winforms, wakeup, sleep-mode

I'm trying to make my pc wake up in case it has gotten into sleep mode. I found this code snippet on some website, but the Messagebox I added at the end always returns immediately.

I have also enabled my system for the use of wake timers in the power options.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr lpTimerAttributes,
    bool bManualReset, string lpTimerName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetWaitableTimer(IntPtr hTimer, [In] ref long
    pDueTime, int lPeriod, IntPtr pfnCompletionRoutine, IntPtr
    lpArgToCompletionRoutine, bool fResume);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr handle, uint
    milliseconds);

    static IntPtr handle;

    private void SetWaitForWakeUpTime()
    {
        long duetime = 1200000000;
        handle = CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr.Zero, true, "MyWaitabletimer");
        SetWaitableTimer(handle, ref duetime, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);
        uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        int ret = WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
        MessageBox.Show("wake up !");
    }
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetWaitForWakeUpTime();
    }
```

Theoretically this should only be signalled after 2 minutes, right?
Why is it signalled right away and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetWaitableTimer() can trigger both on an absolute and incremental time. From the MSDN article:

> *pDueTime* [in]
>  
>   The time after which the state of the timer is to be set to signaled, in 100 nanosecond intervals. Use the format described by the FILETIME structure. **Positive** values indicate **absolute** time. Be sure to use a UTC-based absolute time, as the system uses UTC-based time internally. Negative values indicate relative time. The actual timer accuracy depends on the capability of your hardware. For more information about UTC-based time, see System Time.

Right now you used a positive value so you specified a date in the year 1600, it always instantly completes. Looks like your actual intention was to use a 2 minute *interval* so you must use a negative value, -1200000000.

Probable true intention is to make it wake up at a specific time on the clock, given the usage scenario, use DateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToFileTime()

Comment: Thank you very much. Then why would anyone need a positive value? Who needs a time in 1600? I think I'm not quite grasping the actual meaning of absolute time...